# Iframe sem scroll no Safari Mobile

Tags: css, html5, ios, mobile, iframe

Eu preciso que isso: http://jsfiddle.net/R3PKB/2/embedded/result/, funcione o scroll no body existente dentro do iframe, porém no Safari Mobile ele força o iframe a ter a altura máxima do meu conteúdo e com isso jamais acontece o scroll no body.

Eu preciso que exista esse scroll no body do conteúdo do iframe e não posso mudar ele de posição, pois minha aplicação inteira ouve eventos de scroll e pega posição do scroll do document.

É impossível eu colocar 1 wrapper antes do iframe na minha aplicação ou fazer qualquer outra modificação em que o body do iframe deixará de ter scroll, pois isso vai causa N erros ao ².

O incrível é apenas o Safari Mobile que tem esse comportamento fora do comum.
Alguém tem uma solução?

Comment: Só conheço "soluções" (i.e., [esta](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios) ) que envolvam *wrappers*. De qualquer modo, problemas com *iframes* no iOS são antigos já. Veja se [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari) thread não te ajuda.

Comment: Por isso que é sempre recomendado não usar iframe. Tente fugir dele sempre que possivel.
Já tentou usar  overflow: scroll; no css do iframe
<iframe style="overflow: scroll;">
?

Comment: Entendi, mas se eu colocar <iframe style="overflow: scroll;"> eu perco controle dos eventos de scroll e scrollTop do conteúdo do meu iframe. Isso não resolve. Aparentemente a única solução seria colocar 1 wrapper no conteúdo do meu iframe logo após o BODY e com isso esse wrapper ser a pessoa que ouve scroll e pega o scrollTop.